# 必要だ　必要とする　必要がある　要る - difference

Tags: word-choice

They all seem to mean 'need'. Do some sound stronger than the others? Are all of the following sentences grammatical, and if not which ones are?

お金が要る。

お金が必要だ。

お金を必要としている。

お金の必要がある。

Comment: 「お金の必要がある。」って言わないよね・・

Comment: @Chocolate ４年前からいろいろ学べました。こんな時の投稿を見るとちょっと恥ずかしくなっちゃいます……。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> お金が要る。

I/He want/need the money

(You just saying you need money or want money)

> お金が必要だ。

Money is needed/Cannot be without the money.

(This is more like saying if you need to buy something, you need to have money)

> お金を必要としている。

I/He is needing money.

(This is like saying, you are trying to gathering the money)

> お金の必要がある。

I/He have the need of money.

(You have the need for money.)