# What's the difference between 時間がいる and 時間が必要?

Tags: word-choice, nuances, wago-and-kango

In this thing I'm reading, I see the following sentence:

> 心の傷だって、治るには**時間がいる**でしょ

The speaker is talking about a long standing problem that the protagonist has. It seems like it's 時間が要る, but is there any nuance difference that would cause the author to choose to use that instead of 時間が必要でしょ?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27312/9749

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no significant semantic difference, but 要る is a wago and 必要 is a kango (Sino-Japanese word). This means 必要 sounds relatively stiffer. While 必要 is also a perfect choice here since she is talking about something serious, 要る is mainly used in most casual daily conversations. Perhaps 要る is closer to "need" or "want", 必要 is closer to "require".